# send data from popup to content script after button click

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am making a chrome extension where I want to take user input in the popup and fill the textbox of a page. I have the following code but the data from the popup does not reach the content script.
**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Copy from popup to current tab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "storage"
   ],
    "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Copy from popup to webpage</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type= "text" id = "inp" height='50' width = '200'></input>
    <button id="send">Click Me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Popup.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('send').onclick=LogIn;
  }
function LogIn(){
var data = document.getElementById('inp').value;
chrome.storage.local.set({
    data : data
},function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "content.js"
    });
}
);
}
```

**Content.js**

```
chrome.storage.local.get('data',function(items){
var gotdata = items.data;
chrome.storage.local.remove('data');
});
```

Comment: Your content script is injected twice. Either remove it from manifest or use messaging instead of executeScript.

Comment: can you give me some example, so I can understand?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts): currently you declare a content script in manifest.json so it's injected on every page regardless of what happens in the popup.

Comment: How do you know the data is not getting to the content script? You are not doing anything with `gotdata` so there will be no indication that the data was found.

Comment: I had tried `alert gotdata;`

Comment: @wOxxOm, you are correct, the content script is injected twice. I removed it from the manifest. Thank you all.